# Why are braces mandatory in boxes?

Tags: macros, tex-core, boxes

Both `\hbox` and `\vbox` (and similar box commands) require explicitly to enclose their content inside of curly braces, so they behave differently from macros.  What's the reason of this specification?

If I redefine for instance `\hbox` as a macro, would there be any issue?

```
\let\orihbox\hbox
\def\hbox#1{\orihbox{#1}}
```

Comment: `\hbox` and `\vbox` are not macros but TeX primitives, and as such like many primitives have weird syntax. And you don't have to redefine `\hbox`, just use the LaTeX constructs `\mbox` or `\makebox`.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just wondering why these primitives have this syntax, similar to the syntax of a macro, but with required braces

Comment: Because `\hbox to 5cm {something}` is also valid syntax. And as with every TeX primitive: Because Knuth.

Comment: So to sum up: Yes, there would be issues, you'd kill many LaTeX internals that use some trickery with the `to` or `spread` key-word style parameters.

Comment: Oh, also note that the syntax is even more weird: `\def\startmyfoo{\hbox\bgroup}\def\endmyfoo{\egroup}\startmyfoo This is boxed!\endmyfoo` is valid syntax.

Comment: "If I redefine for instance \hbox as a macro, would there be any issue?" you would completely break latex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\hbox` and `\vbox` are primitives with following syntax:

```
\hbox {horizontal list}
or
\hbox to dimen {horizontal list}
or
\hbox spread dimen {horizontal list}
```

The `\hbox {horizontal list}` opens the TeX group at the beginning of the horizontal list and closes the group at the end of the list. It means that required braces in the syntax is very natural.

Answer (score 3):

You want to tell TeX what should be boxed, don't you?

Actually, explicit braces aren't mandatory: they can be replaced with `\bgroup` and `\egroup` (which isn't possible with argument to macros).

As Skillmon points out in a comment, you can define

```
\def\starthbox{\hbox\bgroup}
\def\finishhbox{\egroup}
```

and

```
\starthbox abc\finishhbox
```

would box `abc`. Maybe this is not so relevant for `\hbox`, but it is for the similarly behaved `\vbox`, `\vtop` and `\halign`. You can do

```
\def\starthboxregister#1{\setbox#1=\hbox\bgroup}
\def\finishhboxregister{\egroup}
```

and doing

```
\starthboxregister{0}abc\finishhboxregister
```

would be equivalent to

```
\setbox0=\hbox{abc}
```

Again, possibly not so useful with `\hbox`, but, for example, `\begin{tabular}` of LaTeX eventually does

```
\halign\bgroup
```

and `\end{tabular}` issues the matching `\egroup`.

By the way, if you do

```
\hbox\relax{abc}`
```

then the result would be to box `abc`, because `\hbox` ignores what the TeXbook calls a ⟨filler⟩.

And `\hbox` (like the similar primitives listed above) performs expansion in order to find `to`, `spread` or an opening brace.

With your proposed redefinition of `\hbox` you'd become able to say

```
\hbox a
```

at the expense of breaking a lot of things; for instance, `\hbox to <dimen>{...}` would suddenly cease to work. Count the number of times `\hb@xt@` appears in `latex.ltx` and *where*.